# spring and n-tier application

Tags: spring, architecture

Its very difficult find any example about spring n-thier application architecture. Spring usually uses local bean, and when we write application so presentation and business tier is in the same server.

But what if we need separate this two tiers, and also use many servers for presentation, business and databases. I need to have got different presentation tier - mobile and web. So my session must be in business logic, also i must use rest to communicate with client. 
Is there any example how to do this uses spring ??

Answer (score 0):

Use spring mvc to expose rest services to all your clients, I mean code your services **to expose only data**, then anyone who wants to consume your service may query your rest endpoint.

Comment: Yes i think about it but what with session and many instances ??